# How can I access the node.depth attribute in the (Grails plugin) <RichUI:treeview> tag?

Tags: grails, plugins, treeview

The plugin says that you can use 'node.depth' from the  tag to determine what label level has been clicked (country or province).  I can't seem to access node.depth from the RichUI:treeview tag.  My code works fine when the value of 1 or 2 is hard coded into the onLabelClick. But when I specify node.depth as the parameter, nothing gets passed to the javascript. How can I access node.depth?  My alert says that "level is undefined"

```
<richui:treeView id="tree" xml="${data}" 
onLabelClick="treeClickHandler(node.depth, id)" showRoot="false"/>


function treeClickHandler(level, id){
    alert("level is " + level + " and id is " + id);
    if (level == 1){
        postForCountryIdeas(id);
    }
    else{
        postForProvControls(id);
    }
}

def index() {
def countryList = Country.list()
def writer = new StringWriter()
def xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
def writer2 = new StringWriter()
def xml2 = new MarkupBuilder(writer2)
xml2.mkp.xmlDeclaration(version: "1.0", encoding: "utf-8")
xml2.countrys {
    countryList.each{item->
        xml2.country(name:"${item.name}", id: item.id){
            item.provinces.each{ prov-> 
            province(name:"${prov.name}", id: prov.id)
            }
        }
    }
}
[data: writer2.toString()]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use node.node.depth instead of node.depth as per the docs.